# Is MySQL able to return mutiple result set with one query?

Tags: sql, mysql, ruby, dbi

I have the following (returning two separate result sets) being successfully executed from a proc but cannot do the same when executing this as a basic query.

```
SELECT * FROM persons;
SELECT * FROM addresses;
```

Possible?  What's the syntax?

EDIT:

I am using Ruby's DBI library:

```
dbh.query("SELECT * FROM persons; SELECT * FROM addresses;")
```

Answer (score 4):

are you talking about from the mysql cli? works fine for me:

```
mysql> select count(*) from a; select count(*) from a;
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|     2050 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.06 sec)

+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|     2050 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

if you're talking about a specific language, then it depends on your mysql library. for example, the PHP mysql library does not support this. however, the mysqli library does if you use multi_query().

Comment: I was thinking of the Ruby DBI library, but I noticed I also couldn't run the above inside the "MySQL Administrator".

Comment: everything i'm reading about ruby DBI points to no. mysql administrator doesn't let you execute two queries and get two result sets, but it does support multiple result sets, for example when a stored procedure has multiple result sets.

Answer (score 2):

JOIN persons and addresses, and you can get a big result table, assuming addresses correlates to persons with some identifier. If the two queries aren't related, why would you want them together?

Comment: Hypothetical example.  In certain instances based on how the records will be handled it makes sense to return each recordset independently.

Comment: It is more efficient to get as much from the DB via a single call as possible.

Comment: Actually, current Rails distributions decide against the join, favoring two distinct select queries, if you do a `Model.includes(:another_model).find(...)` request. I'm pretty sure it is on purpose (probably reduces memory overhead and thus in the end can be faster).

Answer (score -1):

If the data correlates use a JOIN to join address items onto person items. If your tables both contain similar columns you probably want a UNION SELECT like so:

SELECT * FROM people
UNION
SELECT * FROM addresses;

Comment: Union is for tables having like columns.

Comment: How true you are, but you won't believe how many people asked me how to do two SQL queries in one when they actually wanted to do a union select. So this was more or less a pointer for those people. Feel free to undo the downvote... ;-)